# Python Dataframe: Create columns based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with repeated values for one column (here column 'A') and I want to convert this dataframe so that new columns are formed based on values of column 'A'.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(4)*3, 'B':range(12),'C':range(12,24)})
df
    A   B   C
0   0   0  12
1   1   1  13
2   2   2  14
3   3   3  15
4   0   4  16
5   1   5  17
6   2   6  18
7   3   7  19
8   0   8  20
9   1   9  21
10  2  10  22
11  3  11  23
```

Note that the values of "A" column are repeated 3 times.

Now I want the simplest solution to convert it to another dataframe with this configuration (please ignore the naming of the columns, it is used for description purpose only, they could be anything):

```
        B               C
    A0  A1  A2  A3  A0  A1  A2  A3
0   0   1   2   3   12  13  14  15
1   4   5   6   7   16  17  18  19
2   8   9   10  11  20  21  22  23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `pivot` problem, so use

```
df.assign(idx=df.groupby('A').cumcount()).pivot('idx', 'A', ['B', 'C'])

     B              C            
A    0  1   2   3   0   1   2   3
idx                              
0    0  1   2   3  12  13  14  15
1    4  5   6   7  16  17  18  19
2    8  9  10  11  20  21  22  23
```

---

If the headers are important, you can use `MultiIndex.set_levels` to fix them.

```
u = df.assign(idx=df.groupby('A').cumcount()).pivot('idx', 'A', ['B', 'C'])
u.columns = u.columns.set_levels(
    ['A' + u.columns.levels[1].astype(str)], level=[1])
u

     B              C            
A   A0 A1  A2  A3  A0  A1  A2  A3
idx                              
0    0  1   2   3  12  13  14  15
1    4  5   6   7  16  17  18  19
2    8  9  10  11  20  21  22  23
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need `assign` the group help key by `cumcount` , then just do `unstack`

```
yourdf=df.assign(D=df.groupby('A').cumcount(),A='A'+df.A.astype(str)).set_index(['D','A']).unstack()
   B              C            
A A0 A1  A2  A3  A0  A1  A2  A3
D                              
0  0  1   2   3  12  13  14  15
1  4  5   6   7  16  17  18  19
2  8  9  10  11  20  21  22  23
```

Comment: @coldspeed hi cold could you please help I have no idea......https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403072/7964527

Comment: That is weird... I have no idea... I have upvoted both of your answers there. :/

Comment: @coldspeed yep I known just afraid I provided something wrong:-),, seems just random down vote.:-( and you are the best person can hel me to check the accuracy of the answer;-)

Comment: I would suggest not to worry about it. Someone is probably having a very bad day... :)